# Pyspark read csv

Tags: dataframe, csv, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

After read the csv, I'm getting an unexpected output:

```
MessageName;ContactKey;DateTimeSend;MessageContent;MessageOpened;OpenDate;TimeInApp;Platform;PlatformVersion;Status
20200903 - NL SPAARUPDATE Augustus;0031t00000A4w0xAAB;09/03/2020 8:09;Vorige maand heb je dankzij de Lidl-Plus app %%savings%% euro gespaard. Goed bezig! ??????;no;;;iPhone OS;12.4.5;Success
```

As you can imagine, the output required it's the split of this information into columns and cells to create a normal dataframe.

I tried the following code:

```
df = spark.read.csv('/FileStore/tables/BE_August_monthlysaving.csv', header='true')

display(df)
```

Alternatively, I tried to use `, delimiter=';'` before and after the header but when I do this I get the following error:

> csv() got an unexpected keyword argument 'delimiter'

Any idea how to solve this output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `sep` instead of `delimiter`:

```
df = spark.read.csv('/FileStore/tables/BE_August_monthlysaving.csv', header='true', sep=';')
```

Or you can put it as an `option`:

```
df = spark.read.option('delimiter', ';').csv('/FileStore/tables/BE_August_monthlysaving.csv', header='true')
```